# Send command results to batch variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to compare an empty string to the results from a ping using `FIND`. I want to capture only failed ping requests.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
ping -n 1 %choice% | FIND "Request" >> %request%

FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %choice% | FIND "Request") Do @set request =%a
```

Once I get this to set correctly, I plan to compare `request` to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

```
ping -n 1 %choice% | FIND "TTL=">nul && (echo pass) || (echo fail)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to protect the pipe, and have matched quotes in the for command, and use %%:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %choice% ^| FIND "Request" ') Do @set request =%%a
```